# using htaccess to remove ids at the end of url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have some troubles removing the ids at the end of url.
With the following snippet it sort of works but then all the assets such as css and js are not being loaded correctly.

Original url:
http://mywebsite.com/poker-in-englisch/150/1448/98480

should be url:
http://mywebsite.com/poker-in-englisch/

Here is my snippet:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^((?!([0-9]{3})\/([0-9]{4})\/([0-9]{5})).)*/ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Since the ids are always 3 number / 4 number / 5 numbers, I tried to catch everything before that with a negative look up and remove that. Unfortunately none of the css or js works afterwards... and my page looks sort of messed up.

Any help or hint appreciated

Comment: This is probably the “usual” problem with relative paths not being resolved correctly any more, because you changed the path of the base document.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Seo Friendly Url css img js not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working)

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your feedback. I think the issue is similar.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following. Simply checking condition if REQUEST_FILENAME is not a file or directory in local system if yes then do rewriting the rule. In `RewriteRule`'s regex in 1st capture group capturing everything before 1st occurrence of `/` in group 1 and then mentioning digits 3 4 and 5 as per question. On substitution part of url rewriting by mentioning `$1` it will rewrite the uri to first captured part.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/\d{3}/\d{4}/\d{5}/?$ /$1 [L]
```

Comment: Since htaccess is not my forte... please be patient with me. So I literally just copied your syntax in. But the assets are still messed up. I do not quiet understand the request file name part. Could you explain further how it works? I know that $1 returns the captured part. Also I want to tell you that I use wordpress as a cms. My goal is basically old posts from another cms to be still accessible when I moved everything to wordpress.Since the old cms creates articles with those ids at the end. I am not sure if this could answer your question.

Comment: @KNugal, I am sorry but your question don't have these details and it looked  related to rewrite url, now what you have mentioned is looking totally different question to me. IMHO you could open a new question with complete details changing this question's summary now will confuse everyone, please do let me know if this thought works for you.

Comment: its ok I will your answer as a base to study further thanks for the help.