# .htaccess, engine rewrite, regardless everything infront, refer to the same folder

Tags: .htaccess

It has been a while i've played arround with the engine rewrite functions in the htaccess file.
But due some merged projects and some pretty damn ugly looking url's that would be tomuch work for a simple application to work i've decided to use enginerewrite to make things a bit more pretty.

However, like always there is a catch that i've been struggling with for the past 2 days, the image folder.

To give an example, url's are changing to `domain.com/firstpage/firstparam/secondparam/ultimateparam/`
the issue here is the images on the page, that are broken because there is no image folder under the uri `domain.com/firstpage/firstparam/secondparam/ultimateparam/images/`

so my question here is, how can i ignore everything infront of /images/ and make it link to the actual images folder ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-results-in-css-img-and-js-not-working

Comment: It actually does, not the way I expected, but this will do indeed, thanks allot Amit!

Comment: See also the following related question on the Webmasters stack: [.htaccess rewrite URL leads to missing CSS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One awnser profided by Amit Verma.
putting a / infront of the path to the image, ex;

`<img src="path/to/image.png">`

to

`<img src="/path/to/image.png">`

seems based on the (sub)domain.

Not exactly what the question was, but it solved my issue regardless, thanks!