# Pretty RewriteRule back to old format

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have some old urls indexed by Google in format `https://example.com/1234/name-of-page`
Because I don't use these RewriteRules anymore I would like re-route them to `https://example.com?id=1234&name=name-of-page`

How can I do this using .htaccess?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]


RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/title.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml/?$ sitemap.php
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking specifically for uri which starts from `1234/name-of-page` to be rewritten then try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(1234)/(name-of-page)/?$ title.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

For more generic rules you could try following. Please make sure you try either above OR following rules only in your .htaccess file at a time.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)/?$ title.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Made a mistake: re-route has to be: https://example.com/title.php?id=1234&name=name-of-page  (with title.php in front).

Comment: @user1725719, sure, fixed it now, I hope it will work now, let me know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: I got it working right now, but only after I added https://example.com in front of title.php. After that the CSS wasn't loading properly. I fixed that by adding:Don't know if that is smart?  # Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
    RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^.+$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe? 
   g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

Comment: @user1725719, Could you please do add your htaccess file in your question for better understanding of question please.

Comment: Updated my question with htaccess file

Comment: @user1725719, Thank you. could you please do let me know what is the Error you are seeing. I hope these 2 Rules are working fine for you, kindly do elaborate on errors which you are getting, I could see it then.

Comment: Current htaccess RewriteRule is working, but css wasn't loading correct anymore. Therefore I had to add the REQUEST_FILENAME filetypes. I was wondering  if this is really required or there was something else I should fix

Comment: @user1725719, yes for loading of css those conditions could help(you could see this link for [css/images loading related if this helps you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-results-in-css-img-and-js-not-working)). Happy that its working for you. That's why its always good to add your .htaccess file into question itself so that no confusions later, cheers and happy learning.