# Server redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server, subdomain

We wanna make a redirection from root domain to a subfolder

We already tried:
'''

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://example.com/folder1/subfolder/$1 [R=301,L]
```

'''
The redirection works, but internal files also prepend the folder structure so web page doesn´t work as expected.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Seo Friendly URL results in CSS IMG and JS not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-results-in-css-img-and-js-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that those rules also get applied to requested URLs that already contain the rewritten folder structure. So you need to add an exception for those cases:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1/subfolder/
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://example.com/folder1/subfolder/$1 [R=301,END]
```

Such rules should get implemented in the actual http server's host configuration if possible. When using a distributed configuration file instead (".htaccess") you need to accept a performance penalty...