# Why is Apache RewriteRule's result seen only by part of the server functions?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

My website uses a single `index.php` that, while using a single header, `include` a different .php file for each different section of the main page.

`index.php?t=animals` will display a page about animals (with `include animals.php` in some point of the script).

`index.php?t=plants` will display a page about plants, and so on.

However, I want the user to see `website/animals` and `website/plants`, so I'm using the following rule on .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?t=$1 [L]
```

This should internally (i.e. invisible to the user) translate, for instance, `website/animals` into `website/index.php?t=animals`. It's working, because PHP recognizes the `t` variable and includes the correct file (even though `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is returning `/animals` and not `/index.php?t=animals`.

So a problem arises if the user writes `website/animals/`, with a trailing slash, because now many links on the page brake, because they were relative to the root `website/`, not to the `animals` directory.

How can I make everything in the server see `/index.php?t=animals`, i.e. the result of Apache RewriteRule? Or will I have to change every link, including a leading slash representing the root?

Comment: I think you need to set a `base` tag in the header of your web page. See my answer on this post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-results-in-css-img-and-js-not-working

Comment: @AmitVerma Thank you, it works like a charm! Maybe you'll want to add that as an answer.

Comment: @AmitVerma I saw a different error now. A link within the page (starting with `#`) is taking `/` as the base and taking me back to the homepage. Do you know how to avoid that?