# .htaccess remove "?page="

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I have two questions, both related:

1. Using the example url: https://www.example.com/?page=foo.php

How do I use .htaccess to write that out as: https://www.example.com/foo

The second part

2. Using the example url: https://www.example.com/?page=directory/bar.php

How do I use .htaccess to write that out as: https://www.example.com/directory/bar

edit:

In response to please show your current .htaccess

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.  
 <IfModule mime_module>
   AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74___lsphp .php .php7 .phtml
 </IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

## Redirects the index.php file to the root domain
RewriteRule ^index.php$ https://www.digitleseo.com/ [R=301,L]

#redirect  /file.php to /file
RewriteRule ^(.+).php$ /$1 [L,R]
# now we will internally map /file to /file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.php [END]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you .

```
RewriteEngine on
#redirect /?page=foobar.php to /foobar
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(?:index\.php)?\?page=([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule .* /%1? [L,R]
###the rule bellow will internally forward the new URL to the old one
# not an existent file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#rewrite the request /foo/bar to /?page=foo/bar.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /?page=$1.php [L,END]
```

Comment: Thanks Amit. I can see why this should work. but its not for some reason.

Does my file structure matter behind the scences? e.g. example.com/?page=services.php

is serving a page from /content/services.php. index.php is checking the variable page and outputting based on that result

Comment: @scriptmonkey The rule I posted only rewrites requested URIs of the following formats `/foo` or `/foo/bar`  .  What happens when you type `/foo` ? Do you see the contents of `/?page=foo` on the same URI?

Comment: /foo gives the contents of /?page=foo.php ... However when i navigate to /?page=foo.php it does not get rewritten as /foo

Comment: also if i go example.com/directory/foo it doesn't pick up the css

Comment: @scriptmonkey please try the updated the code . To fix your css issue please see this post
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-results-in-css-img-and-js-not-working

Comment: thats a great link/explanation/resolution for the css thank you. I feel like I'm being very annoying here. The re-written rules works perectly as per what id asked and what you've written. The only issue i enconter now is when i navigate to www.example.com/foo and attempt to navigate to bar i get www.example.com/foo?page=bar.php and no movement

Comment: @scriptmonkey The rules I posted above should be placed at the top of your htaccess or before your other rules otherwise those rules can conflict with this.

Comment: yeah i hadn't had them up there. I have moved them but i still encounter the same issue. Ill navigate to say example.com/foo then when i go to another page even home ill get example.com/foo?page=bar.php

Comment: @scriptmonkey Try the updated version. I added an END flag.  I tested the code on my server it's working fine for the URLs.

Comment: i can understand whats going on (because im sat here with a cheatsheet) but i dont understand why its not working. I know this is bad practice but i dont know how to host a codepen equivalent of this in a sandbox. the website thats causeing the issue is www.digitleseo.com/ but I've done everything you've suggested but i still have the /foo?page=bar.php issue

Comment: Could it be something to do with the way im linking to them ... all my links are <a href="?page=foo.php">foo</a> or <a href="?page=bar.php">bar</a>

Comment: @scriptmonkey your links are ok. The first rule above changes these links to the new format , `/?page=foo.php` to `/foo` . Are there any other rules in your htaccess or just these 4 Rewriterules ?

Comment: Just these 4 re-write rules ... i even deleted the ones the server admin asked me not to... 
logically all i can think is there anyway of checking and deleting characters between / and ?page e.g. /foo?page=bar.php i would need to delete foo to return /?page=bar.php and then step through the rules as normal... i dont know. i feel like ive made something quite simple. quite complicated (also checked your profile as soon as i can login to my PP ;) )

Comment: @scriptmonkey Then, I think its a browser chache related issue. Try  clearing your browser cache or test your URLs in a different browser. Your site is working fine when I visit `www.digitleseo.com/?page=foo.php` I can see the URL `www.digitleseo.com/foo`

Comment: @scriptmonkey the only issue I can see with your site is when I type `/?page=foo/bar.php` I get the page with no stylesheet and your href links changed to `/foo/bar?page=foo` this is because you are using relative links. Use a base tag to solve this issue.

Comment: Ahh thank you ver much @Amit ill sort that out right now... 'Googling base tag'

Comment: @scriptmonkey The base tag is mentioned in the linked SO post  . Please read the post again from my comment above.

Comment: Thank you Amit!! perfect

Comment: @scriptmonkey your welcome ! Glad it worked out. Cheers:)

Answer (score 0):

here is my file htaccess, which I use to delete controler and leave the controller name as path and the action name as path.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    ErrorDocument 404 http://shop.local/error/index

    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?controller=$1&action=$2
</IfModule>
```