# How can I create friendly url redirection made form absolute url's in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, seo

I'm writing a program that creates custom friendly urls for websites in .htaccess file. The problem is that I want to create redirect from  `absolute` friendly url to another `absolute` "real" url, because .htaccess file is placed in root directory and websites are placed in many different child directories.

If the pages were placed in the same folder, I could do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule site site.php
RewriteRule site-two site-two.php
```

but the pages are placed in different child folders, so the above code doesn't work.

I tried to do something like this but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule http://www.randomdomain.com/sites-dir/site/ http://www.randomdomain.com/content/sites-dir/site.php
RewriteRule http://www.randomdomain.com/sites-dir/site-two/ http://www.randomdomain.com/content/sites-dir-two/site-two.php
```

I would not like the solution to be similar to 301 redirect because with it, .htaccess refers to another page, but does not save the friendly address in the url bar.

I also want linking pages using a friendly url to be possible.

Does anyone know the solution to this problem?
Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: I tried to do something like this 
`RewriteRule http://www.randomdomain.com/sites-dir/site/.....` You can't do this. 
`RewriteRule` can not match against Full URL. Only URL path can be checked in pattern of a RewriteRule .  So it should be  changed to `RewriteRule ^sites-dir/site/..........`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I tried this solution before but it points to the right page but the friendly address is not kept in the address bar. I don't know much about htaccess and maybe I'm making a stupid mistake somewhere.

This is what i tried:
RewriteRule ^sites-dir/site/ h-t-t-p://www.randomdomain.com/content/sites-dir/site.php             h-t-t-p preventing linking in a comment

Comment: Are you writing this rule just to remove `.php` extension from your URLs? `RewriteRule ^sites-dir/site/ /content/sites-dir/site.php` should work . You just need to remove the sitename from the Rule's destination otherwise the rule will make an external URL redirection

Comment: Thank you now it works, but there is another problem with photos and css not loading after rewriting, but I can see that the topic is popular, so I don't want to take your time and I will read about it. Thank you!

Comment: Alex89 Glad it worked. Please see this StackOverflow post to fix your CSS and JS issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-results-in-css-img-and-js-not-working . Thanks so much.

Comment: @AmitVerma Do not post answers here within the comments. Create an answer that can be accepted and post it there. [answer]