# I would like to change ugly address link on my subpages of galleria (Gallery)

Tags: .htaccess, hyperlink, short

[**grimlord.eu/galeria**](http://www.grimlord.eu/galeria) and its subpages has ugly adress.

```
http://www.grimlord.eu/index_pl.php?src=gallery&sub=koncertowe
http://www.grimlord.eu/index_pl.php?src=gallery&sub=studio
http://www.grimlord.eu/index_pl.php?src=gallery&sub=grimhall
```

I need **[www.grimlord.eu/galeria/koncertowe](http://www.grimlord.eu/galeria/koncertowe)** therefor I changed adress link on my serwer in galeria.html file

```
<area shape="rect" coords = "460,105,655,155" href="http://www.grimlord.eu/galeria/koncertowe" alt="koncertowe" target="_self">
```

In htaccess I have such a situation. Please help me in free time.

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^start$ index_pl.php?src=home [L]
RewriteRule ^grimshop$ index_pl.php?src=shop [L]
RewriteRule ^biografia$ index_pl.php?src=formacja&sub=historia [L]
RewriteRule ^dyskografia$ index_pl.php?src=material [L]
RewriteRule ^galeria$ index_pl.php?src=galeria [L]
RewriteRule ^recenzje$ index_pl.php?src=media [L]
RewriteRule ^koncerty$ index_pl.php?src=konfrontacje [L]
RewriteRule ^kontakt$ index_pl.php?src=kontakt [L]
RewriteRule ^linki$ index_pl.php?src=linki [L]
RewriteRule ^galeria/koncertowe$ index_pl.php?src=gallery&sub=koncertowe [L]
```

The trouble is when I click the link and then  page seems devastated.
[www.grimlord.eu/galeria/koncertowe](http://www.grimlord.eu/galeria/koncertowe)

Maybe in galeria.html is the solution?

```
<map id="mapka" name="mapka">
<li><area shape="rect" coords = "460,105,655,155" href="index_pl.php?src=gallery&sub=koncertowe" alt="koncertowe" target="_self"> 
<area shape="rect" coords = "440,160,610,205" href="index_pl.php?src=gallery&sub=studio" alt="studio" target="_self">
```

Comment: Try using a base tag in the header of your webpage `<base href="/">` should fix it. See this post for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-results-in-css-img-and-js-not-working

Comment: Hello Amit Verma. Pls tell me where? I haven't <head> in galeria.html. I have <head> in index.html

Comment: Put it in between  `<head> and </head>` of your document

Comment: Ok I did it in index.html but when I click www.grimlord.eu/galeria/koncertowe link works, but on url it still appear long http://www.grimlord.eu/index_pl.php?src=gallery&sub=koncertowe

Comment: Have you used RewriteRule ^galeria/koncertowe$ index_pl.php?src=gallery&sub=koncertowe [L,R] ?

Comment: Yes I used this code