# htaccess beginner: absolute location of links

Tags: .htaccess

I have no experience with htaccess and I'm at a loss for what I did wrong.

This works well for site.com/electronics, /index. It redirects to correspoding .php link.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^electronics/([a-zA-Z]+) electronics.php?type=$1 [NC,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

However, when the url is electronics/(type) and I click on a page in the nav bar, the url becomes electronics/electronics/(type) or electronics/index, etc. I am not sure what to do, do I change the url in the nav bar to its absolute location? But, I do not know how to do that either.

Comment: This seems more related to your `<a>` tags than anything in `.htaccess`

Comment: Try using `<base href="/">` in the head section of your document. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-results-in-css-img-and-js-not-working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Seo Friendly URL results in CSS IMG and JS not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-results-in-css-img-and-js-not-working)

Comment: How does the the URL (<a href="...">) in the nav bar look like? Typically right click on the link, then select "Inspect element" or similar.