# remove keys and keep only values from url params

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

real url - `subdomain.example.com?id=3&s=lorem-ipsum`
wanted - `subdomain.example.com/3/lorem-ipsum`
here is my try:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?id=([^&]*)&s=([^\s&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

result - wanted url is there but browser  shows the 404 error - Not Found
pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a `404` error because the redirected URL  `subdomain.example.com/3/lorem-ipsum`  doesn't exist on your server. To fix this,  you need to map this new URL format to its original location `subdomain.example.com?id=3&s=lorem-ipsum` .

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?id=([^&]*)&s=([^\s&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]
#map new URL to the old one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ /?id=$1&s=$2 [L]
```

Comment: now the page is there but all links - css, images etc - are ruined

Comment: @qadenza Yes, that's because you are using relative links for JS, CSS and images. You can fix this using a base tag in head of your document. See my answer on this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-results-in-css-img-and-js-not-working