# Errors with htaccess

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, url

Today I tried to write a .htaccess file for first time in order to remove .html extension from url bar along with some other things that I wanted to do. Since I was unfamiliar with all this I read several articles before coding.

I ended up with the following code. I also removed .html from all links. The problem is that when visiting my domain I get the following error.

```
//The resource you are looking for has been removed, 
//had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Is my code correct?

**UPDATED .htaccess**

```
//Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

//Remove .html UNTIL NOW THIS IS THE ONLY PART 
//OF THE CODE THAT ACTUALLY WORKS.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

//Caching schema
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png)$">
Header set Cache-Control "private, max-age=160704000"
</FilesMatch>

//Prevent viewing of .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

In a separate .htaccess

```
//Prevent directory listings
Options All -Indexes
```

**MAIN ERRORS**
If I click on link like:

```
<a href="index">Home</a>
```

Then I get the same error.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Did you have success with my answer?

Comment: I am working on it :)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992183/how-to-hide-the-html-extension-with-apache-mod-rewrite

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally managed to resolve  a part of the problem. For starters I changed my server from windows to linux.

Then to remove html extension I used this code in .htaccess (the other codes didn't work well, giving me an error message)

```
//Remove .html
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

I also removed any .html instances from all links. 
Now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This is native in Apache without using `mod_rewrite` by using `MultiViews` option.

[Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html) states:

> The effect of MultiViews is as follows: if the server receives a request for /some/dir/foo, if /some/dir has MultiViews enabled, and /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the server reads the directory looking for files named foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's requirements.

Comment: I tried the code suggested in the post but with no results. I still get the same error.