# How can I remove .html from subdirectory folder?

Tags: html, .htaccess

I am currently trying to get to grips with .htaccess.

On my website, my about.html page (which is just a basic text HTML page) works fine with what I have managed so far:

```
mywebsite.com/about.html
```

works and shows as:

```
mywebsite.com/about
```

I have another section called:

```
mywebsite.com/works/
```

Which is full of `.jpg` and `.html` files and several folders. I currently have:

```
mywebsite.com/works.html
```

working which opens up that page and displays all my works as thumbnail .html links which can be clicked and accessed.

I want the website to display this page as:

```
mywebsite.com/works
```

instead of:

```
mywebsite.com/works.html
```

I don't have any issues with my `about.html` page because it is just one HTML page, but as `works` is a folder, when I type:

```
mywebsite.com/works.html
```

it shows up as it should but when I remove the `.html` I get:

```
mywebsite.com/works/
```

As a Fancy Directory listing!

How can I simply change this so that it just shows up as:

```
mywebsite.com/works
```

Comment: Had this once. I added an empty folder named like file, in your case "works" and problem solved.

Comment: Where would I have to add that empty folder ?

Comment: Same folder as file works.html

Comment: I meant to what Miomir Dancevic answered

Answer (score 1):

Create like this

**works/index.html**

And try to access like

**www.example.com/works/**

Comment: Thank you, that works fine. Would it possible to remove the second / ?

I would prefer

mywebsite.com/works

rather than 

mywebsite.com/works/

Answer (score 0):

you can put a copy of works.html with name of index.html this can solve your purpose.

you can also restrict listing by adding

'Options -Indexes' in your .htaccess.

Comment: Hi, thank you, this works, but it shows up as 

mywebsite.com/works/ 

is it possible to remove the second forward slash ?

Answer (score 0):

Gumbo's answer in the Stack Overflow question [How to hide the .html extension with Apache mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992183/how-to-hide-the-html-extension-with-apache-mod-rewrite) should work fine.

This should also work in a sub-directory path:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]
```