# How to show different url from actual one in status bar

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following button that redirects to the given page on button click. I want that instead of http://localhost:8181/RestServiceProject/index2.html this url showing on the status bar, it shows http://localhost:8181/RestServiceProject/GetDetails

How to do this in html?

```html
<form action="http://localhost:8181/RestServiceProject/index2.html">
<button type="submit">Get Order Details</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You mean you dont want http://localhost:8181/RestServiceProject/GetDetails url?

Comment: There isn't a way of spoofing url's unforunately. Most you could do is change your htaccess to remove the .html on the end of your file.

Comment: perhaps you would like to implement some aliases. Check these out https://www.google.com/search?q=mod_rewrite+clean+urls , http://pixelcode.co.uk/tutorials/webmaster/clean-urls-with-mod_rewrite/ , http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls

Comment: Server side URL rewriting?  The configuration depends on the Web server you are running, basically it's .htaccess for Apache and HttpModules for IIS.

Comment: You could also do it on the client using the History API, or the history.js library.  But why you would want to do that puzzles me ....

Comment: In the second page, add `window.status = "http://localhost:8181/RestServiceProject/GetDetails";`

Comment: @Kieran That would work for me. Please tell me how to do that?

Comment: @Natasha [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4026967/7096052) is how you can do it for php. Changing it to html shouldn't be too difficult

Comment: @ScottMarcus Where in the second page? Inside the body tag?

Comment: In a script element.

Comment: try using anchor tag instead of a form `<a href="http://localhost:8181/RestServiceProject/index2.html"> <button>Get Order Details</button>
</a>`

Answer (score 0):

The easies way of doing that would be renaming index2.html to GetDetails.html and changing the action url to GetDetails without any extnsion. Next and last thing to do is removing extensions from the url using .htaccess [see more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992183/how-to-hide-the-html-extension-with-apache-mod-rewrite). Remember that you have to use server which will read your .htaccess.

Answer (score -1):

That would be done with the server.

For example, if you're using an Apache server, using `URL Rewrite`: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html