# My Website does not seem to like the removal of .html and I can't fix it

Tags: html, .htaccess, ubuntu

I have tried to remove the .html at the end of my url with this code in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

But as you can see when you go to [my website](http://www.multicrew.co.uk/downloads.html) it just redirects to the link without the .html and says forbidden. I also have

```
Options -Indexes
```

In my .htaccess file but removing it doesnt fix the problem.

EDIT: If I put .html at the end of the url it works but if I remove that it says Forbidden

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide the .html extension with Apache mod\_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992183/how-to-hide-the-html-extension-with-apache-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

This should remove `.html` from your URLs. Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: I did that but I get a "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace." Error

Answer (score 0):

This should work with apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

I've also done it this way with my own site (using .htaccess on apache):

```
# Automatically redirect /index.html files to their URL directory
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: If you go to www.multicrew.co.uk/downloads.html it redirects to just /downloads/ which says the requested URL is not found.

Comment: Never mind, I'm an idiot, but the .htaccess file edit still has no effect on the downloads page.