# Remove extension .html through .htaccess in sub directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

First off - sorry for asking this question again. It seems to be answered a million times - but I still can't get my .htaccess to work.

**The problem:**
In **public_html** we have a working website and an .htaccess file. In a **sub-directory** called "**staging**" we have another website running which is totally independent from the website in public_html. How can I address the sub-directory with an .htaccess in order to remove the .html extensions? We are on a apache server with cPanel, shared hosting (Hostgator).

**.htaccess in public_html**

```
# -- concrete5 urls start --
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]


</IfModule>
# -- concrete5 urls end --

<IfModule mod_headers.c>    
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
</IfModule>
#Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

**.htaccess in staging**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Any (detailed) help or instructions would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Why `RewriteBase /` in the dynamic configuration file inside the `/staging` folder?

Comment: You have explained your setup, but what is the problem? Is the `staging` directory served by a different domain?

Comment: Isn't the "base" related to a specific directory? Even if I use the code displayed above without the line "RewriteBase /" - it doesn't work.

Comment: Olaf: The problem is, that I am not able to display the links in the url bar without the extension .html.

Comment: `RewriteBase` is for some relative URLs only.

Comment: What do you mean, do you get a 404 not found, or an empty page, or a server error?

Comment: None of that. But in order to display certain navigational parts of the website in question correctly and to improve SEO I need to eliminate the .html. This is the site: http://olex.org/at/index.html

Comment: I can't help, when I don't know what the problem is, because the `staging/.htaccess` looks good at first sight. So again, when you enter `http://staging.example.com/some/path/test`, what happens?

Comment: I am not talking about a sub domain but a sub directory. http://example.com/staging, http://example.com/staging/single-page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep the `staging/.htaccess`, but remove [`RewriteBase /`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase), because this causes the relative substitution path `$1.html` to be searched at `/$1.html` instead of `/staging/$1.html`.

> The RewriteBase directive specifies the URL prefix to be used for per-directory (htaccess) RewriteRule directives that substitute a relative path.

You also don't need the [`NC|nocase`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc), because the pattern doesn't contain any "alphabetic" letters.

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the code edit. Unfortunately the .html extensions are still there. I have no clue what's going on...

Comment: What does that mean? When you enter `http://www.example.com/staging/some/path/test`, does the appropriate `.../test.html` show?

Comment: Thank you Olaf. When I type in the url directly without the .html extension the pages do now load properly. So I think that your code suggestion does work! My guess is that I need to manually remove the .html from the links inside the page in order to get the urls displaying without the .html

Comment: Yes, this must be done in your code, it cannot be done by .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you could use this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

in subdirectory or modify parent htaccess.
As I tested it at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ it works.

Are your pages real static html pages or html addresses are generated by some CMS's links system?

Comment: All the pages are static pages only - no CMS attached.

Comment: You could try these solutions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992183/how-to-hide-the-html-extension-with-apache-mod-rewrite