# htaccess url rewrite .html page version to non .html version (bug :www.http//)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all my old pages (mywebsite.com/help.html) to (mywebsite.com/help).

So I just added this code in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{4,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
```

it's working but I get a strange issue when I try this URL:

mywebsite.com/page.html

I get this result

www.http//mywebsite.com/page/

You can see URL rewrite adding this invalid code in the start of the page url (((www.http//))

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f  
RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]
```

Took from [How to hide the .html extension with Apache mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992183/how-to-hide-the-html-extension-with-apache-mod-rewrite)