# mod_rewrite causing extra slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to simply remove .php from the filenames on URLs. I'm implementing the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992183/how-to-hide-the-html-extension-with-apache-mod-rewrite) StackOverflow answer so my VirtualHost looks like this,

```
# domain: example.com
# public: /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/
<Directory /var/www/html/example.com/public_html>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        # Admin details
        ServerAdmin vanguard@example.com
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
        #Index File
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public_html
        #Log Details
        LogLevel warn
        ErrorLog /var/www/html/example.com/log/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/html/example.com/log/access.log combined
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
        RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Going to `https://example.com` resolves just fine, but if I try to go to `https://example.com/examplefile` it rewrites it to `https://example.com//examplefile/`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the result of your server-config directives? Do you have other directives in `.htaccess`? Incidentally, those mod_rewrite directives won't work as-is in a virtual host context. The `RewriteCond` directive will never match. (But, rather perplexingly, despite the highly upvoted/accepted answer on [that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992183/how-to-hide-the-html-extension-with-apache-mod-rewrite), those directives would not work as-is in `.htaccess` either?!)

Comment: @MrWhite There isn't any `.htaccess` in the `/public_html` directory. Why won't those rules work in either virtual host or .htaccess, and then how I do correct it?

Comment: "it rewrites it to" - Presumably you mean "redirect"? ie. you see the double slash in the URL in the browser? If so, what HTTP status code are you seeing? The only redirect in your above config is HTTP to HTTPS (which is a 302 here - this should ultimately be a 301 once you've finished testing). Make sure the browser cache is cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
> RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]
> ```

In a virtual host context this `RewriteCond` directive will never match because at the time the directive is processed the request has not yet been mapped to the file system, so `REQUEST_FILENAME` simply contains the URL-path (as opposed to the absolute filesystem path), which is the same as `REQUEST_URI`.

(This wouldn't work in `.htaccess` either, but for a different reason. In `.htaccess` you can't rewrite to an absolute filesystem path, so whilst the `RewriteCond` should match, the `RewriteRule` is likely to trigger a 403 Forbidden error.)

To fix this in a server/virtual host context, you can modify these directives to use a URL-based look-ahead:

```
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !\.php$ %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]
```

However, neither your original directives nor this correction explains the double slash you are seeing in your example. Either an erroneously cached response or your web application?

Comment: Strangely that worked and fixed the trailing slash issue.