# Page redirection not working unless I add .html to the URL

Tags: html, redirect

I had a client that gave a URL in a press kit before the website was done. He gave a page when I was making the website a one page site. So I took the URL he made and coded it as a redirect to scroll to that part of the site.

Now that I have it online, it isn't working properly.

fuzzripper.com/bio gives me an internal server error
fuzzripper.com/bio.html works just fine

I would like it to work even if the user doesn't type .html

Here is my redirect code

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=http://www.fuzzripper.com/#about">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href = "http://www.fuzzripper.com/#about"
    </script>
    <title>Page Redirection</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Note: don't tell people to `click` the link, just tell them that it is a link. -->
    If you are not redirected automatically, follow this <a href='http://www.fuzzripper.com/#about'>link</a>.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Apart from the fact that code redirects to `#about` (not `bio`), `bio` is a different file from `bio.html`, in the same way that `helloworld.doc` is a different file to `helloworld.docx`

Comment: You could check web server redirections. Like mod_rewrite for apache. This let you create RewriteRules to make things like the one you are asking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide the .html extension with Apache mod\_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992183/how-to-hide-the-html-extension-with-apache-mod-rewrite)

Comment: @ChrisW - It is supposed to redirect to the #about div on the index page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix for static sites is to

1. Create a `/bio` folder
2. Move `bio.html` in bio folder
3. Rename `bio.html` to `index.html`

This should make the `bio#about` link work just fine.

Comment: Such a simple solution I didn't even think of. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are very welcome ! It happens to me all the time.