# Renaming url in php - basic settings

Tags: php

I am trying rename the urls for my website for the first time.  I do not have any complex re-routing or get requests in my urls.

The current url is

```
www.example.com/index.php
www.example.com/createproject.php
```

I want this to be changed to

```
www.example.com/index
www.example.com/project
```

My folder structure for the above php files is as follows

```
/var/www/html/index.php
/var/www/html/createproject.php
```

The defaultssl conf is set to point to `/var/www/html` folder.  I am trying to re-write the url through the `.htaccess` file, which is placed in

```
/var/www/html/.htaccess
```

and I have used the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule index index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule project createproject.php [NC,L]
```

In my website, I have a sidebar that contains the urls for these pages.  For example:

```
echo '<div class="nav">';
echo '<div class="sb-sidenav-menu-heading">Core</div>';
echo '<a class="nav-link" href="index.php"';
echo '><div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i></div>';
echo 'Dashboard</a';
echo '>'
```

The above is a part of sidebar rendering through a php file.  I am not sure if I have to change this line

```
echo '<a class="nav-link" href="index.php"';
```

to

```
echo '<a class="nav-link" href="index"';
```

This along with the above .htaccess and combinations of these - none of them helped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide the .html extension with Apache mod\_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992183/how-to-hide-the-html-extension-with-apache-mod-rewrite)

Comment: And yes, you should use proper URL's in links too

Comment: @justinas sorry not working...i did not change the urls they still have the .php extension.  do I have to restart the apache to apply .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure .htaccess file is enabled in apache if not then visit this link [how enabled .htaccess in apache](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429869/is-this-a-correct-way-to-enable-htaccess-in-apache-2-4-7)   after that

you need to put below code in your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]
```

and the sidebar HTML should be like this

```
echo '<div class="nav">';
echo '<div class="sb-sidenav-menu-heading">Core</div>';
echo '<a class="nav-link" href="index"';
echo '><div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i></div>';
echo 'Dashboard</a';
echo '>';
```

you need to remove .php from this line

```
echo '<a class="nav-link" href="index"';
```

it will work for you

Comment: Thank you....I guess enabling the htaccess in apache had helped....coz even my earlier code works now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^([^.*]+)/?$ index.php?file=$1&lang=en [QSA,L]
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css|php|svg)$">
 FileETag None
 <ifModule mod_headers.c>
 Header unset ETag
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
 Header set Pragma "no-cache"
 Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
 </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

Then include the requested file in the index.php file:

```
$file= $_GET["file"];
include($file);
```

I hope it helps

Comment: It's more like security hole here. You basically can include any PHP file that contains credentials