# Remove .html file extension in SUBDOMAIN url

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, server

I have found some posts and answers with htaccess files that do remove the .html file extension. However, none of those work when the files are in a subdomain.

What I want to achieve is this - subdom.mysite.com/index.html -> subdom.mysite.com/index

Comment: Are you missing a ".com" in the redirect url?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide the .html extension with Apache mod\_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992183/how-to-hide-the-html-extension-with-apache-mod-rewrite)

Comment: As I said, these do NOT work when in subdirectory.

Comment: Add an htaccess file to the subdirectory which has the sub domain. And add the code you got which work in the main domain. It is that easy :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try that:

RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ /$1 [L,R=301]