# htaccess redirect subfolder .php file to trailing slash

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, trailing-slash

I've tried all sorts of suggestions for .htaccess but nothing seems to work for some reason.

All i want is to redirect all of the .php files in http://www.pokertips.org/blog/ to a non-php ending. I've tried it with a .htaccess file in the /blog/ folder but still not working. I can get it to redirect so that it changes in the address bar, but it always results in a 404 error message.

For example:
http://www.pokertips.org/blog/how-to-create-a-great-atmosphere-for-your-home-poker-game.php

redirects to

http://www.pokertips.org/blog/how-to-create-a-great-atmosphere-for-your-home-poker-game/

Also, just for reference, if anyone can tell me how it would work the other way around, i.e. a trailing slash redirecting to a .php ending, that would be useful too for another project.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us what you've tried already. Add the content of your .htaccess file(s) to your question.

Answer (score 0):

That's possible using QSA (Query String Append), see example below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

[Please see this post for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992183/how-to-hide-the-html-extension-with-apache-mod-rewrite/1992191#1992191)

This should work for your subdirectory, Don't forget that you can lose the indexing of google if you change the URL of your pages.